# Split pandas dataframe by column then append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe:

[image]

I want to keep the first three columns, then stack them on top of the next 3 cols, such that I have a dataframe with just `["userID", "tweetID", "time"]` in the end.

Comment: Please, do not share data as picture but in *text* in order to easily reproduce. Nobody want to write data by hand. Also, in order to produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), edit the question with the desired output.

Comment: @AlexandreB. I shared it as a picture as I thought it would be easier to visualize. Also, the desired output is at the end of the question. I simply want to take columns whose name ends in "_end" and stack them under the first 3 columns.

Comment: @Qubix, it is a lot easier for SO helpers if the input is textual, as the data can be copied into a running python interpreter. also if the expected output as text, it can be compared to the produced output through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('_').map(lambda x : '_'.join(x[::-1]))
s=pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['end','start'],i='index',j='drop',sep='_',suffix='\w+').stack().unstack(-2)
```

Comment: this does not work: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 100 rows, received array of length 3

Comment: @Qubix check the update , this is just my understanding , if still not match what you need, please include the expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
df_top = tree_df[['userID_start', 'tweetID_start', 'time_start']]
df_top.columns = ['userID', 'tweetID', 'time']
df_bottom = tree_df[['userID_end', 'tweetID_end', 'time_end']]
df_bottom.columns = ['userID', 'tweetID', 'time']
final_df = pd.concat([df_top, df_bottom])
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

```
start_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.endswith('_start')]
end_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.endswith('_end')]

def rename(x): return x.split('_')[0]

output_df = pd.concat([
    df[start_cols].rename(columns=rename), 
    df[end_cols].rename(columns=rename)
])
```

You can subset the start & end columns in two dataframes & pd.concat them together to stack.